# Convert JSON key value pairs into JSON Array Android

Tags: android, json, encode, key-value, arrays

I have an array of key-value pairs like this:

```
{
  "320x240":"http:\/\/static.example.com\/media\/content\/2012\/Jul\/mercedes-benz-a-klasse-red-t_320x240.jpg",
  "300x225":"http:\/\/static.zigwheels.com\/media\/content\/2012\/Jul\/mercedes-benz-a-klasse-red-t_300x225.jpg",
  "200x150":"http:\/\/static.zigwheels.com\/media\/content\/2012\/Jul\/mercedes-benz-a-klasse-red-t_200x150.jpg"
}
```

What I'm doing currently is this:

```
   try {

      images_object = new JSONObject(imageList);//imageList is a String of the above array //of key value pairs

            Iterator<?> keys = images_object.keys();
            String string_images = "";
           if(keys.hasNext()) {
               String key = (String)keys.next();
                String value = (String)images_object.get(key);
                string_images = "[" + value;  
           }
            while( keys.hasNext() ){
                String key = (String)keys.next();
                String value = (String)images_object.get(key);
                string_images = string_images + "," + value;

            }
            string_images = string_images + "]";
            String encoded_json_string = JSONObject.quote(string_images);
            images = new JSONArray(encoded_json_string);//images is of type JSONArray but it is null
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But, images, is NULL. Why's that? What am I missing?

Comment: Because you're not creating valid JSON. `string_images` will in no way resemble valid JSON which requires strings to be quoted.

Comment: Could you tell me what is wrong? I also tried removing the square brackets.

Comment: @Namratha What is your problem with the below answer? Have you tried that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get all values from current `JSONObject` in `JSONArray` as:

```
Iterator<String> keys = images_object.keys();
JSONArray images = new JSONArray();
while( keys.hasNext() ){
    String key = keys.next();
    String value = images_object.optString(key);
    //add value to JSONArray from JSONObject
    images.put(value);
}
```

**EDIT**

Simplified solution is get the keys with `images_object.names()` and you can pass `JSONArray` of keys to `toJSONArray` method to get the value with respect to keys in `JSONArray`

```
JSONArray keys=images_object.names();
JSONArray values=images_object.toJSONArray(keys);
```

To Summing up simplified solution is:

```
JSONArray images=images_object.toJSONArray(images_object.names());
```

Comment: The method add(String) is undefined for the type JSONArray.

Comment: @Namratha : then you can use JSONArray.put . see my edit answer

Comment: Okay, thanks. But, could you tell me what was wrong with my method?

Comment: @Namratha : ok then tell me what u are getting in `string_images` string ?  u have any issue with my answer?

Comment: @Namratha : im  sure u are not getting right string in `string_images` for converting to JSONArray.so just use Logs for checking string_images variable vale before converting to JSONArray

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Hi brother no need iterate through the keys, just use `images_object.names()` which will return `JSONArray` of keys directly

Comment: @Pragnani : hi, but i think requirement is to get value associated with name or keys in JSONArray

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK oh..sorry for that.. I thought OP wants keys

Comment: @Pragnani : you are also right, we can use both way for getting keys then use while or for loop for getting associated values from JSONObject

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK But Simplified one is this `JSONArray images=images_object.toJSONArray(images_object.names());` without iterating through the keys we can get the associated values in `JSONArray`.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Please include above comment in answer so that it will  help others..It will do the things in one line

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Sorry I have suggested you to include this `JSONArray images=images_object.toJSONArray(images_object.names());`, please check my edit your answer

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Above solution will give values in JSONArray format not keys